# MySQL - Changing FT_MIN_WORD_LEN (my.ini)

Tags: windows-server-2003, mysql, sql, configuration, full-text-search

I've recently asked my server administrator, for my Windows dedicated server, to change the MySQL configuration file (my.cnf) to allow search words of 2 characters or more, from the default of 4.

They said they have changed it, restarted MySQL and re-booted the server but I have seen no changes. I've rebuilt the indexes only on the tables that this particular script uses, using the REPAIR TABLE method but still doesn't work as it should.

Is this right? After searching my server for my.ini files? Seeming as 5.0 is my latest version.

[image]

Version 4.1 has two files in C:Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1 and two files in C:Documents and Settings\manage\Desktop\MySQL Server 4.1, my latest version, 5.0, only has one .ini file in C:Program Files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to create a custom stopword list because there are 640 words that are excluded from FULLTEXT indexes. Some of those two letter words omitted are: on, of, it, is. [*Take a look at the full list*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

Perform the following

Step 01) Create a `stopwords.txt` file

```
echo "a" > C:\mysql_stopwords.txt
echo "an" >> C:\mysql_stopwords.txt
echo "the" >> C:\mysql_stopwords.txt
```

Step 02) Add these line to my.ini

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file=C:/mysql_stopwords.txt
```

Step 03) Restart mysql

```
net stop mysql
net start mysql
```

Step 04) [**Reindex all FULLTEXT indexes**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9921/877)

Sorry I forgot this was Windows. I changed my answer to reflect Windows,

Comment: Thanks for that. I have noticed that the variable ft_min_word_len is in the section [mysql] not [mysqld]. The stop words are not an issue as it's names we are searching for, such as Al Pacino, Tom Cruise and Amy Smart, which all have first names less than the default 4 characters

Comment: I also ran **show variables like 'ft_min_word_len';** and it returns 4 still

Comment: Did you restart mysql ???

Comment: The server administrator said he did, so I take his word for it...